# PySNMP returning different values on different machines

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

A script I developed on my laptop runs fine there, but on a remote server it isn't returning what I'd expect.

My server has this output:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2014, 18:11:42) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pysnmp
>>> print pysnmp.__version__
4.2.5
>>> 
>>> from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
>>> cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
>>> 
>>> errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
...     cmdgen.CommunityData('communitystringhere'),
...     cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.10.10.10', 161)),
...     '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2',
...     lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True)
>>>     
... for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
...     for val in varBindTableRow:
...         print val
... 
(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1)), OctetString('fxp0'))
(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.4)), OctetString('lsi'))
(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.5)), OctetString('dsc'))
(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.6)), OctetString('lo0'))
[Output truncated...]
```

The results are a MibVariable and OctetString.

On my laptop, I get the following:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pysnmp
>>> print pysnmp.__version__
4.3.2
>>> 
>>> from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
>>> [code ommitted, same as above...]
...
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.2.2.1.2.1 = fxp0
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.2.2.1.2.4 = lsi
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.2.2.1.2.5 = dsc
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.2.2.1.2.6 = lo0
[Output truncated...]
```

I'm not sure what could be making pysnmp return differently, other than the minor version - but the older version (on the server) seems to have much nicer output than the 'newer' version on my laptop?

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the default `str` representation of the `MibVariable`object (or `ObjectType` in later pysnmp versions) changed between minor pysnmp versions...

Can you call `.prettyPrint()` on the `varBind`? It would hopefully produce a uniform representation across different pysnmp versions:

```
for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
  for varBind in varBindTableRow:
    print(varBind.prettyPrint())
```

As a matter of hack, you can probably mimic the old `str` representation like this:

```
...
>>> varBind = varBinds[0]
>>> name, value = varBind
>>> '%s(%s(%s), %s(%s))' % (
    type(varBind).__name__, 
    type(name).__name__, 
    name, 
    type(value).__name__,
    value
)
'ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0), DisplayString(Linux zeus 4.8.6.5-smp #2 SMP Sun Nov 13 14:58:11 CDT 2016 i686))'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using a similar method to yours to mimic.

Comment: Though I'm not certain what is your ultimate goal here? Do you need to know the exact SNMP types returned?

Comment: No, I'm essentially just trying to walk that OID to get back all the values. I have a search string I'm trying to find in that table, with the last part of the OID being the index of the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: If you know SNMP table index (tail part of the OID), do you really need to walk the agent? It looks like you can do a single query for a fully known OID(s) then...

Comment: Depending on whether or not you want your value to be formatted with MIB definition or use it in a raw form, you may try to regexp either `value.prettyPrint()` or `value.asOctets()`.

Comment: Cheers, I know the ifDescr, and I'm walking to try and find the index so I can cache it.